# How to change the key of a sonar project while preserving the analysis history

Tags: sonarqube

Due to the integration with Eclipse, the project key of my existing Sonar project needs to be changed.  I can change the project key in the ant script and trigger a new analysis.

However, Sonar considers it as a new project because the key is different now.  This doesn't work for me because my existing project has quite a lot of history information.
How can I change the project key while preserving the analysis history? Or, is there a way to merge 2 sonar projects?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### Sonar 3.2+

This is supported since sonar 3.2 (August 2012) from an option in the adminstration.
[image: sonar screenshot]

Ticket: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-1608

#### Older versions

In [this feature-request SONAR-2743](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-2743) you can find a workaround for prior versions, that could work (don't forget to backup you database before even trying).
It requires you to manually execute some sql-statements on the database.

Comment: @Zitrax thx, I will add a screenshot of the new functionality as soon as 3.2 is released